# Why jQuery event not firing when outside ready function, even after document is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

Why does click event not firing in this case, although DOM appears to be loaded ('ready' shows in the console)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");
});

$("p").click(function() {
    alert("You clicked on paragraph.");
});
```

My understanding, that because code for click event is after document ready function is correctly executed, it should work, but it doesn't. It will only work when event is included between curly braces in ready function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$(document).ready` is asynchronous. You are passing a callback function to it so that it logs the fact the DOM is ready. However, the `click` binding code is being executed immediately after you set up the `ready` handler, not when the callback has executed.

You just need to make sure you put the binding logic within the `ready` handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the code directly in the `$(document).ready()` function or create a new function that binds the click when the `DOM` is ready.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        bindClickEvent();
    });

    function bindClickEvent() {
       $("p").click(function() {
           alert("You clicked on paragraph.");
       });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click me!</p>
```

Comment: That is very useful. Definitely gonna use this technique as it makes code cleaner having function prototypes at the top of the file. Kudos.

Answer (score 2):

If you want that code to be executed in the "ready" event, just move it there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready!");

    $("p").click(function() {
        alert("You clicked on paragraph.");
    });
});
```

The way you defined it right now doesn't mean it is executed when the DOM is loaded.