# Handle Django form submit using javascript to prevent normal submission

Tags: javascript, django, post

I'm trying to prevent django following normal form submission using javascript. It looks like program never entering javascript. Here is the code

```
{% load static %}
<form  method="POST" id="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{formPost.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Post </button>
    </form>


<script>
 $('#post-form').on('submit', function(event){
    console.log("Inside Javscript!")
    event.preventDefault();
    create_post();
});
</script>
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: how you inserting script tag in base or template?

Answer (score 0):

probably because your script is not inside `$(document).ready`.
see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665382/why-jquery-event-not-firing-when-outside-ready-function-even-after-document-is)